# Can't move character in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move my character (a spaceship) in pygame but what I have done so far has not worked. Everything runs and it displays the character but it does not move when I press the keys.

```
class Player:
    vel = 10
    x = width/2-PLAYER.get_width()/2
    y = 450

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw_player(self, win):
        win.blit(PLAYER, (self.x, self.y))


def main():
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 30
    while running:
        bg = Background(0, 0)
        bg.draw_background()
        sc = Score(f"Score: {score}", WHITE)
        sc.draw_score()
        player = Player(50, 50)
        player.draw_player(win)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders Game")

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player.x += 1
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            player.x -= 1

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(fps)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance of a class, the constructor is executed and the object attributes are initialized. Hence, you continuously create a new `player` in his starting position. You are drawing the player at the same position over and over again. Actually the player is moving, but you never see the movement because a new player is immediately created at the starting position to replace the first player.
You must create the instance object of the `Player` class **before** the application loop instead of **in** the application loop:

```py
def main():

    player = Player(50, 50)       # <--- ADD

    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 30
    while running:
        bg = Background(0, 0)
        bg.draw_background()
        sc = Score(f"Score: {score}", WHITE)
        sc.draw_score()

        # player = Player(50, 50)    <--- REMOVE
        
        player.draw_player(win)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders Game")

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player.x += 1
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            player.x -= 1

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works now! So in other words I was just drawing the player over and over again in the same position? It makes sense now that I think about it.

Comment: @Caleb Yes you were drawing the player over and over again at the same position.